visual studio docker compose uses cache
.net webapi app, using docker-compose
a supposedly quick and easy question - how to make visual studio invalidate the docker image and rebuild it? I have tried clearing the solution as well as removing the image container/itself from docker itself - but the visual studio keeps using the cache of some sort
For comparison - when I execute the command manually:

docker-compose build --no-cache

I get an error that the file I am trying to COPY does not exist. This is the expected behavior and the error I would like to see in the visual studio!

COPY ["fileThatDoesNotExist.config", "."]

When I rebuild/clean/run the solution in the VisualStudio and the docker-compose run profile is used - it keeps starting up the solution without any errors!

In the build order console window I see the following log
2>#5 [myservice base 2/2] WORKDIR /app
2>#5 CACHED
2>#6 [myservice] exporting to image

It makes no sense for him to keep using the cache because I've changed the contents of the dockerfile and it needs to be rebuilt (and expectedly fail)
In docker-compose dcproj file I tried setting the

<DockerComposeBuildArguments>--no-cache</DockerComposeBuildArguments>

but it has no effect whatsoever
so my question is - how to make the visual studio forcefully rebuild the whole image and fail? or alternatively, what can I do in order to clean the cache? (I also don't want to prune the entirety of docker infrastructure)

That seems like ordinary docker build caching: if you change one of the files that is COPYed into the image then it will rebuild from there.  The WORKDIR line doesn't depend on any of your application code, especially if it's the first thing after the FROM line, and it will probably always show as "cached" (and that's okay).

@DavidMaze I can confirm that running the docker build command docker build -f .\src\myservice\Dockerfile . produces the same kind of error as if I run the docker compose command. This is good and an expected behavior. What's not expected is that the Visual Studio keep ignoring the change in dockerfile and starts up the project without any errors whatsoever.

VS has 2 separate files to override docker-compose.yml.You may want to check if
docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml
or
docker-compose.vs.release.g.yml
is present in your solution and modify them aswell.

This is probably Visual Studio using Fast mode, which is the default in the Debug configuration. In Fast mode VS doesn't build the full image and uses volume mounts to bring in your locally built code (as the name suggests, this is much faster). If you want VS to build the full Dockerfile you can set the property DockerDevelopmentMode to Regular in your .dcproj.
